# Operation not Permitted on ALSA get hw parameters functions

Tags: c, alsa

I am trying to play pcm audio buffers receiving from server. I downloaded one example alsa play back file giving recorded file as input its working fine but the same code I added in my SIP client application am getting Operation not permitted error. Open device and setting configuration for the device are OK but trying to get parameters what I configured gave me `Operation not permitted error`.
Can anybody tell me the reason why I got this error?

```
/* Open the PCM device in playback mode */
    if (pcm = snd_pcm_open(&pcm_handle, PCM_DEVICE,
                                    SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0) < 0)
            printf("ERROR: Can't open \"%s\" PCM device. %s\n",
                                    PCM_DEVICE, snd_strerror(pcm));

    /* Allocate parameters object and fill it with default values*/
    snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);

    snd_pcm_hw_params_any(pcm_handle, params);

    /* Set parameters */
    if (pcm = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(pcm_handle, params,
                                    SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED) < 0)
            printf("ERROR: Can't set interleaved mode. %s\n", snd_strerror(pcm));

    if (pcm = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(pcm_handle, params,
                                            //SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE) < 0) 
                                            SND_PCM_FORMAT_MU_LAW) < 0)
            printf("ERROR: Can't set format. %s\n", snd_strerror(pcm));

    if (pcm = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(pcm_handle, params, channels) < 0)
            printf("ERROR: Can't set channels number. %s\n", snd_strerror(pcm));

    if (pcm = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(pcm_handle, params, &rate, 0) < 0)
            printf("ERROR: Can't set rate. %s\n", snd_strerror(pcm));

    /* Write parameters */
    if (pcm = snd_pcm_hw_params(pcm_handle, params) < 0)
            printf("ERROR: Can't set harware parameters. %s\n", snd_strerror(pcm));

   /* Resume information */
    printf("PCM name: '%s'\n", snd_pcm_name(pcm_handle));

    printf("PCM state: %s\n", snd_pcm_state_name(snd_pcm_state(pcm_handle)));

    pcm =  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_channels(params, &tmp);
    printf("channels: %i  %d", tmp, pcm);

    if (tmp == 1)
            printf("(mono)\n");
    else if (tmp == 2)
            printf("(stereo)\n");

    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate(params, &tmp, 0);
    printf("rate: %d bps\n", tmp);

    printf("seconds: %d\n", seconds);

    /* Allocate buffer to hold single period */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params, &frames, 0);

    buff_size = frames * channels * 2 /* 2 -> sample size */;
    buff = (char *) malloc(buff_size);

    printf("buffsize: %d\n", buff_size);
    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(params, &tmp, NULL);
```

Comment: You should check the return value of all function calls. Anyway, which function fails?

Comment: Thanks for Reply                        snd_pcm_hw_params_get_channels, snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate and snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size all above function are getting Operation not permitted and return value is 0

Answer (score 0):

All your error checks are wrong.

The `<` operator binds stronger than `=`, so in a line like this:

```
if (err = snd_something(...) < 0)
```

the return value of the function is compared against zero, and the result of that comparions (false or true, 0 or 1) is assigned to the variable.

To make this work correctly, you would have to add parentheses around the assignment:

```
if ((err = snd_something(...)) < 0)
```

But it is a much better idea to not try putting everything into a single expression:

```
err = snd_something(...);
if (err < 0)
```

Comment: snd_pcm_hw_params_get_channels(params,&tmp) snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate(params, &tmp, 0); return success(0) and argument has to get the values  what i have to set i.e, 8000 and 1 but  both function values setting to 1 and operation not permitted error

Comment: "Operation not permitted" is the error with code 1. I explained why that is not the real error code.

Comment: when i run it as separate code i got parametres(sample rate and channels) what i configured.When the same code include in my sip client am getting this issue and no sound when i write audio buffers on alsa device. Can you please tell what is the wrong am doing ?

Comment: Did you actuall read and understand my answer? If you make these changes, you will get the correct error code.

Comment: I modified my code as you said and  got return value 1.Any solution to overcome this.?

Comment: Show the actual code. Which function returns that error code?